# Finding all active threads

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsthread

I need to find a way to enumerate all my iPhone application's active threads. This is strictly for debug purposes. Private APIs, if any, are welcome as well. I know I can see all the current threads in the debugger window, but I would like to have access to the actual NSThread objects, if that is at all possible.

Comment: Why u can't using nsoperationqueue? U can just add objects there and access to them

Comment: [This question has been asked before here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351229/how-to-loop-through-all-active-thread-in-ipad-app), where I note that one answer stated, "This seems fraught with peril, doubly so if you need to ask here for help". Wondering what the problem is that you're trying to actually solve here?

Comment: Thx man; But can you help to answer my related question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47071265/how-to-analyze-stack-trace-info-of-a-thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can have a look at what has already been answered here :

[How To Loop Through All Active Thread in iPad app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351229/how-to-loop-through-all-active-thread-in-ipad-app/6419996#6419996)

PLCrashReporter is referenced as well here but some other things built on top of it.

Comment: Thx man for reference PLC; But can you help to answer my related question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47071265/how-to-analyze-stack-trace-info-of-a-thread

Answer (score 2):

I think that PLcrashreporter is probably what you are looking for - if you need to understand how it can access all of the active threads then I suggest you consider looking through the source code there:

http://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/

Comment: Thx man; But can you help to answer my related question to PLC? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47071265/how-to-analyze-stack-trace-info-of-a-thread