# How To Loop Through All Active Thread in iPad app

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, ios, callstack

In the iPad app that I'm creating, I'm trying to handle the uncaught Exceptions by outputting the callStackSymbols of the exception. This can be done with `[NSException callStackSymbols]`

However, I'd like to be able to see the callStackSymbols on all the other active threads as well. I know I can use `[NSThread callStackSymbols]` on any thread, but I need to loop through all the active threads to do so.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is a complex area, as Sedate Alien noted. You will need to implement your own stack walking to retrieve a stack trace from the other active threads; APIs such as backtrace(3) and +[NSThread callStackSymbols] will only produce a backtrace for the current thread.

Since I'm familiar with the PLCrashReporter code, I'll just use it for examples:

- To fetch the thread list, you'll need to use [task_threads()](http://web.mit.edu/darwin/src/modules/xnu/osfmk/man/task_threads.html): https://opensource.plausible.coop/stash/projects/PLCR/repos/plcrashreporter/browse/Source/PLCrashLogWriter.m?at=refs%2Ftags%2F1.0#694
- Once you have the thread list, you can fetch the thread state via [thread_get_state()](http://web.mit.edu/darwin/src/modules/xnu/osfmk/man/thread_get_state.html): https://opensource.plausible.coop/stash/projects/PLCR/repos/plcrashreporter/browse/Source/PLCrashFrameWalker_arm.c?at=refs%2Ftags%2F1.0#73
- Using the thread state, you can walk the target's stack:
  https://opensource.plausible.coop/stash/projects/PLCR/repos/plcrashreporter/browse/Source/PLCrashFrameWalker_arm.c?at=refs%2Ftags%2F1.0#104

Note that all this code is a bit unusual, as it executes within a signal handler and is written to be async-safe; if you're unfamiliar with the complications around signal handling, this is a good starting point: http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-04-01-signal-handling.html

Implementing this kind of thing correctly is a gigantic headache; I would really recommend that you make use of PLCrashReporter, or one of the products built on top of it ([QuincyKit](https://github.com/TheRealKerni/QuincyKit/), [HockeyApp](http://www.hockeyapp.net/), [Atlassian JMC](http://www.atlassian.com/en/jiramobileconnect), etc).

Comment: Thx man so much for pointing out; But can you help answer my related questions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47071265/how-to-analyze-stack-info-of-a-thread

Comment: what a great answer. links to the APIs. Links to example code. Bang on!

Answer (score 4):

This seems fraught with peril, doubly so if you need to ask here for help. May I suggest [PLCrashReporter](http://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/)? Its listed features are:

- Implemented as a in-process fully async-safe signal handler.
- Does not interfere with debugging in gdb
- Handles both uncaught Objective-C exceptions and fatal signals (SIGSEGV, SIGBUS, etc)
- **Backtraces for all active threads are provided.** (emphasis my own)
- Provides full register state for the crashed thread.

Better yet, have a look at [QuincyKit](http://quincykit.net/), a very handy wrapper around PLCrashReporter.

Comment: While this is a good third party solution, I'd still rather learn about looping through active threads. Even if you could point me in the right direction as far as documentation goes, I would find that more helpful.

Comment: Thx so much for reference PLC; But can you help answer my related questions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47071265/how-to-analyze-stack-info-of-a-thread