# Get thread specific info in iOS crash report?

Tags: ios, xcode, crash-dumps, crash-reports

I'm using the following code to get crash reports from my iOS application:

```
void *frames[128];
int i,len = backtrace(frames, 128);
char **symbols = backtrace_symbols(frames,len);

NSMutableString *buffer = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:4096];

NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
[buffer appendFormat:@"PComp version %@ build %@\n\n",
    [bundle objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"],
    [bundle objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CIMBuildNumber"]];
[buffer appendString:@"Uncaught C++ Exception\n"];
[buffer appendString:@"Stack trace:\n\n"];
for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    [buffer appendFormat:@"%4d - %s\n",i,symbols[i]];
}
```

This will only give information about the current thread?  How could I get this stack trace for all threads?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this question.

[How To Loop Through All Active Thread in iPad app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351229/how-to-loop-through-all-active-thread-in-ipad-app)

The most voted response actually explains what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [ATOS](http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2009/Feb/msg00238.html)? ([Address to symbol](http://www.eigo.co.uk/Deciphering-iPhone-Crash-Logs.aspx))