# HOWTO get the correct Frame Pointer of an arbitrary thread in iOS?

Tags: ios, c, stack-trace, callstack, stack-frame

## Way to get the Frame Pointer

[image]

On a Demo App running on iPhone 5s Device / Xcode 7, I tried to get the `frame pointer` of an **arbitrary** thread using [`thread_get_state`](http://web.mit.edu/darwin/src/modules/xnu/osfmk/man/thread_get_state.html) , but always result in an incorrect one :

```
- (BOOL)fillThreadState:(thread_t)thread intoMachineContext:(_STRUCT_MCONTEXT *)machineContext {
    mach_msg_type_number_t state_count = MACHINE_THREAD_STATE_COUNT;
    kern_return_t kr = thread_get_state(thread, MACHINE_THREAD_STATE, (thread_state_t)&machineContext->__ss, &state_count);
    if (kr != KERN_SUCCESS) {
        char *str = mach_error_string(kr);
        printf("%s\n", str);
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

I read the frame pointer like this: `uintptr_t fp = machineContext.__ss.__fp;`, according to Apple Doc ([ARMv6](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iPhoneOSABIReference/Articles/ARMv6FunctionCallingConventions.html) and [ARM64](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iPhoneOSABIReference/Articles/ARM64FunctionCallingConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013702-SW1)),

> Register R7 is used as a frame pointer on ARMv6

while x29 on ARM64

> The frame pointer register (x29) must always address a valid frame record, although some functions—such as leaf functions or tail calls—may elect not to create an entry in this list. As a result, stack traces will always be meaningful, even without debug information.

```
_STRUCT_ARM_THREAD_STATE64
{
    __uint64_t    __x[29];  /* General purpose registers x0-x28 */
    __uint64_t    __fp;     /* Frame pointer x29 */
    __uint64_t    __lr;     /* Link register x30 */
    __uint64_t    __sp;     /* Stack pointer x31 */
    __uint64_t    __pc;     /* Program counter */
    __uint32_t    __cpsr;   /* Current program status register */
    __uint32_t    __pad;    /* Same size for 32-bit or 64-bit clients */
};
```

## Way to prove the Frame Pointer is wrong

How do I prove that the fp (`machineContext.__ss.__fp`) is not a correct frame pointer?

1. If the parameter is the current thread, mach_thread_self() for example, the **fp is always 0**, which is different from `__builtin_frame_address(0)`;
2. If the parameter is not the current thread, main thread for example, the pointer to the previous frame pointer of `fp` will be NULL in two or three frames, which is too short for a normal link-list of stack frames;
3. Still not the current thread, I print out the call stack addresses using `backtrace` on main thread before `sleep`. Then on another thread, I suspend the main thread and read the frame pointer using `thread_get_state` to walk the call stack, the two backtrace buffers are totally different;

## What confuses me

[Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iPhoneOSABIReference/Articles/ARM64FunctionCallingConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013702-SW1) says **The frame pointer register (x29) must always address a valid frame record**, but I could read a **ZERO** value from it.

Furthermore, [`ARM Doc`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0055b/IHI0055B_aapcs64.pdf) states **In all variants of the procedure call standard, registers r16, r17, r29 and r30 have special roles. In these roles they
are labeled IP0, IP1, FP and LR when being used for holding addresses**.

Below is an example of part of `_STRUCT_MCONTEXT`'s value:

```
Printing description of machineContext:
(__darwin_mcontext64) machineContext = {
  __es = (__far = 0, __esr = 0, __exception = 0)
  __ss = {
    __x = {
      [0] = 292057776134
      [1] = 6142843584
      [2] = 3
      [3] = 40
      [4] = 624
      [5] = 17923
      [6] = 0
      [7] = 0
      [8] = 3968
      [9] = 4294966207
      [10] = 3603
      [11] = 70
      [12] = 0
      [13] = 33332794515418112
      [14] = 0
      [15] = 4294967295
      [16] = 4294967284
      [17] = 18446744073709551585
      [18] = 4295035980
      [19] = 0
      [20] = 0
      [21] = 0
      [22] = 17923
      [23] = 624
      [24] = 6142843584
      [25] = 3
      [26] = 40
      [27] = 3
      [28] = 0
    }
    __fp = 0
    __lr = 6142843568
    __sp = 6877072044
    __pc = 6142843488
    __cpsr = 2582105136
    __pad = 1
  }
  __ns = {
```

## What I am looking for

**I'm now searching for a method to get the correct value of the `Frame Pointer` of an arbitrary thread**.

Thanks for any help!

## UPDATE 1

Of course, What I want is to get the correct `Frame Pointer` of the leaf stack frame of an arbitrary thread, and then walk the call stack along the `Previous Pointer` of the `Frame pointer`.

Before this, I've read these links:

[Getting a backtrace of other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402160/getting-a-backtrace-of-other-thread)

[How To Loop Through All Active Thread in iPad app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351229/how-to-loop-through-all-active-thread-in-ipad-app)

[Printing a stack trace from another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765158/printing-a-stack-trace-from-another-thread)

Thanks again.

## UPDATE 2

I've tried on other platforms, but yet the same result : **wrong frame pointer**.

```
- (uintptr_t)framePointerOfMachineContext:(_STRUCT_MCONTEXT *)machineContext {
#if defined (__i386__)
    return machineContext->__ss.__ebp;
#endif

#if defined (__x86_64__)
    return machineContext->__ss.__rbp;
#endif

#if defined (__arm64__)
    return machineContext->__ss.__fp;
#endif
}
```

The value `framePointerOfMachineContext` returns is not the same to `__builtin_frame_address(0)`.

## UPDATE 3

Inspired by a colleague, I tried inline asm and made it on i386:

```
uintptr_t ebp = 1;
__asm__ ("mov %%ebp, %0;"
         :"=r"(ebp));

uintptr_t builtinFP = (uintptr_t)__builtin_frame_address(0);
```

Now `ebp` variable holds the same value to `builtinFP`'s. But HOWTO do this on an arbitrary thread?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the problem eventually,

```
- (BOOL)fillThreadState:(thread_t)thread intoMachineContext:(_STRUCT_MCONTEXT *)machineContext {
    mach_msg_type_number_t state_count = MACHINE_THREAD_STATE_COUNT;
    kern_return_t kr = thread_get_state(thread, MACHINE_THREAD_STATE, (thread_state_t)&machineContext->__ss, &state_count);
    if (kr != KERN_SUCCESS) {
        char *str = mach_error_string(kr);
        printf("%s\n", str);
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

`thread_get_state` is fine, but the parameter should be architecture-specific, such as `x86_THREAD_STATE32`, `x86_THREAD_STATE64` and etc.

I misunderstood the macro `MACHINE_THREAD_STATE`, which gave me an universal meaning for different architectures.